# Loop through Togglebuttons in Activity

Tags: java, android, widget, togglebutton

I'm looking to loop through all the Togglebuttons I have in one activity and do one of two things.  In one case I want to set their values, in another case I want to read their values.  Is the easiest way to do this to loop through the children, try to check their type for togglebutton and then preform the previously mentioned tasks?

Would I use something like this?

```
     for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++)
       if (Widget_Tag != null){   
       View Current_Widget = (View) rootView.getChildAt(i);          
       String Widget_Tag = (String) Current_Widget.getTag();
       if (Widget_Tag.equals("MyToggleButton")) {
         //do something
       }
     }
```

*********UPDATE***************

Working code as follows (thanks for answer), I nested another for-loop to dig down one child layer for my ToggleButtons:

```
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.LayoutHere);
    for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++) {
      ViewGroup nextLayout = (ViewGroup) rootView.getChildAt(i);
      for (int i2 = 0; i2 < nextLayout.getChildCount(); i2++) {
          View Current_Widget = nextLayout.getChildAt(i2);          
            if(Current_Widget instanceof ToggleButton) 
            {                     
              //Do Something
            }                         
      }         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing would work if you have tagged your `ToggleButton`'s with the `String` "MyToggleButton" like this:

```
ToggleButton button = getSomeToggleButton();
button.setTag("MyToggleButton");
```

If you have not done something like the above previously, then your code snippet will not work.  You could do an `instanceof` check on each `View`.

```
if(Current_Widget instanceof ToggleButton) {// or instanceof MyToggleButton if that is a class of yours...
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I guess I overstepped my bounds a bit, this code was from a related post and wasn't sure if it was totally for me.  With your answer I think I have it setup correctly but I'm having trouble with the rootView, I thought it might have been a standard function but it needs to be defined.  When I'm trying to define it, it's looking for a ViewGroup but I'm not having any luck getting rootView setup as a ViewGroup correctly.

Comment: Figured it out, was only getting 1st level of children, had to dig down another level based on my layouts.  **Updated Question to reflect working info**